# Add styles to icon of react-native-paper button element

Tags: button, icons, styles, react-native-paper

I use button in react-native-paper with icon. I need to add a shadow style only to the icon of the button. The only available option I found was to add an elevation to the button. But it is applied to the whole button instead of applying only to the icon of the button.

**The code of button:**

```
<Button
  icon={icon}
  onPress={onPress}
  size={size}
  color={color}
  animated={animated}
  disabled={disabled}
  style={styles.btnStyles}
/>
```

**The Style of button to add shadow:**

```
btnStyles: {
  elevation: 40,
  shadowColor: '#000',
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
},
```

**The result:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odJ4c.png) 
(Here you can see that the shadow is applied to the button, not to the icon inside.)

How can I solve above issue and add a shadow only to the icon?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no option to style icon in react-native-paper, so you can design your own custom with TouchableOpacity according to your requirement.